# How to debug Serverless framework using typescript with VSCode

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, vscode-debugger

I have a serverless framework project using **typescript** and I am trying to debug the project on VSCode, all my breakpoints are shown as "unbound breakpoints" and I am unable to debug the project all all.

here my `launch.json` file :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug locally",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/sls",
            "args": [
                "invoke",
                "local",
                "-f",
                "helloWorld",
                "--data",
                "{}"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--lazy"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/.webpack/**/*.js"
            ],
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "runtimeExecutable": "node"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am doing sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I imagine that your `launch.json` does the same then `sls invoke local -f helloWorld --data {}` is this command working at least ?

Comment: What is your folder structure under /.webpack like?

Comment: @TheSmartMonkey yes the command works

Comment: @eli6 the structure is `.webpack/service/src/handler/helloWorld.js`

Comment: have you generated your code with a specific template or how have you set up your project?

Comment: not sure how it was generated @eli6, I am taking over this project from another developer